# AWS device farm with Espresso and JUnit4

Tags: android, unit-testing, amazon-web-services

I want to test my app in AWS farm, using

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit-mock:1.9.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.1.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.2.0'
```

Sample test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) and run with AndroidJUnitRunner, I have my tests starting like:

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class EstimationActivityTests {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(LoginActivity.class);

@Before
public void setup() {
}

@Test
public void showsRightDataOnCreate() {
org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("asd", "asd");
}
}
```

But it just test teardown and setup suite tests... looks like it dont recognize the tests...

Another thing is that I´m creating the apk and test apk with gradlew.

```
#./gradlew assembleMockAndroidTest
```

and I upload the files in `app-mock-androidTest-unaligned.apk` and `app-mock-unaligned.apk`.

What´s wrong in my process?

Case: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=647198&#647198

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All tests clases names should end with "Tests" and test functions should start with "test" and then it will work.

Answer here http://makingiants.com/blog/run-espresso-tests-on-amazon-aws-farm-test-center/

Comment: It seems like that there is something else that needs to be done apart from the naming conventions. Let me know if there is anything else that needs to be done to resolve the problem.